# Can't install packages with NuGet - 500 internal server error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

This makes no sense to me. NuGet was working fine before but now it is throwing a server error when I try to install packages. I've uninstall and reinstall NuGet with the latest, but still no luck.

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  EntityFramework
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Has anyone seen anything like this? Thanks.

I'm pointed at `https://nuget.org/api/v2/` which seems to be live...

Comment: just got this myself!  whats going on nuget?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it's at least not me. Tearing my hair out over here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From NuGetTeam (@nuget) on Twitter https://twitter.com/#!/nuget

> We are investigating an issue on the NuGet Gallery servers. We will
>   provide an update shortly. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

Happened to me too.

Try this:

1. Run VS in admin mode.
2. Uninstall NuGet from Tools->Extension Manager (Extensions and Updates in VS 2015)
3. Delete everything in short `%AppData%\NuGet` or full-named `C:\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`
4. Reinstall NuGet

Answer (score 2):

Retry, it works now over here.

Comment: Thanks, it's back to life now.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has this error sometimes. Try restarting your visual studio (I have 2019). If it still doesn't fix, repair your VS installation. **This is certainly for future viewers as I also had this problem and fixed by restarting VS**

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on a fresh Visual Studio 2017 Community.
Closing the task (ending hanging task) and restarting Visual Studio with ADMIN rights solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this HTTP 500 server error on a local Nuget source, go the website (e. g. http://mynugetsource/nuget/Packages) to get more information about the error.

In my case, a .nupkg file was opened one someone's computer. Closing the file solved the issue.