# System.Net.Ping NuGet Installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, arm, nuget, uwp

I would like to use System.Net.Ping NuGet reference in a UWP Project with ARM target. I want use Ping in Windows 10 Mobile.

I'm trying with "Install-Package System.Net.Ping -Version 4.0.0" but i get same message with lastest preview (Install-Package System.Net.Ping -Pre)

Output:

System.Net.Ping 4.0.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Ping in UAP, Version = v10.0, but there is no assembly in
Runtime compatible with win10-arm
Line: 1 Character: 1
+ Install-Package System.Net.Ping -Version 4.0.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : One or more packages are not compatible with UAP, Version = v10.0 (win10-arm)

Same message for win10-arm-aot,win10-x64,win10-x64-aot....

Maybe, can't i use these library with ARM target?

Comment: did you tried [Can't install packages with NuGet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10130759/3796048)

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class is not supported by UWP since ICMP is still not supported in UWP yet. You can use [winrt-vasily](https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-vasily) as a workaround for now.

Comment: Thanks, but a simple telnet aren't a solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, the System.Net.Ping package is not compatible with UWP app. I have tried install on a command C# Class Library project, it could install correct. And I also check the dlls contained in this package with NuGet Package Explorer, I found that there only .NET Framework 4.6 dll in this packages. Other platform folder is empty.
[image]

Comment: Sorry for delay. Thanks, I tried too with another Project with same result as you.

Comment: So according to the assembly that contains in this package, it should support .NET 4.6 at present, not compatible with UWP app.